# Declaring variables in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

## Background

I have been using Amazon Redshift to execute my queries.
I know there was a question asked earlier regarding this. But I don't understand how to incorporate UDFs.

I want to assign a temporary variable which takes a particular value.
I want to do this to make my script dynamic. For instance- This is my
usual way of writing code.

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_table WHERE invoice_date >= '2013-01-01' 
AND invoice_date <= '2013-06-30';
```

## What I want to do is ...

Something like what you will see below. I believe SQL server has a declare variable which does this sort of a thing.

```
SET start_date TO '2013-01-01';
SET end_date TO '2013-06-30';

SELECT * FROM transaction_table WHERE invoice_date >= start_date 
AND invoice_date <= end_date;
```

This way I don't have to search deep in my script. I can just have a set
statement up top and just change that.

Your feedback is greatly welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no variables in Redshift, unfortunately. You can, however, get a variable-like behaviour by creating a temporary table and referring to it as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _variables AS (
    SELECT
        '2013-01-01'::date as start_date
      , '2013-06-30'::date as end_date
);
SELECT
    transaction_table.*
FROM
    transaction_table, _variables
WHERE
    invoice_date >= start_date
AND
    invoice_date <= end_date
;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out today and let you know

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. This will save me a lot of time.

Comment: Careful with this: this is a join that can really damage performance. Up to 100x in my experience. Consider using the query ```select transaction_table.* from transaction_table where invoice_date >= (select start_date from variables) and invoice date <= (select end_date from variables)``` instead.

Comment: Old answer but there are variables in redshift now
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-structure.html

Comment: it won't work if you have read only permissions

Answer (score 1):

Redshift does have the ability to do this, though it's hidden in the docs. You can use a session context variable that lasts as long as the session in which it was created. The naming convention has to be a two-part name separated by a dot (ex:  `identifier.identifier`). Details are buried in the [SET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SET.html) and the [CURRENT_SETTING](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_SETTING.html) documentation.

Here's an example:

```
SET context.my_variable TO 89;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = CURRENT_SETTING('context.my_variable')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Read-only permissions other answers won't work. Here's my solution

```
WITH _variables AS (
    SELECT 42 AS my_value
)

SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column = (SELECT my_value FROM variables);
```